# How to reset the windows password of another laptop's hdd?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, password-recovery

I have a password reset request for the windows on a laptop. The BIOS seems to be locked and the owner doesn't remember it's password. I have taken out the 2.5" hdd and plugged it in to my windows computer. I use hiren's boot cd to recover passwords but for some reasons it's not recognising the target hdd (maybe because it's connected via usb). Is there a way to reset the windows password on this disk without booting?

Comment: [How to clear an unknown BIOS or CMOS password](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000235.htm)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's an acer laptop and the top chassis seems to be superglued to the body. Perhaps someone has had a look at it before myself, broken some parts and superglued it, denying any access to motherboard components.

Comment: If the bios is locked on the original computer then putting the hard disk in another computer will not help. You need to fix the problem on the original computer.

Comment: I understand but a temporary fix (since the client needs it tonight before boarding the plane) would be to get the admin account working. I am trying chntpw utility on my ubuntu. Will update here if it works out.

Comment: Good luck ... :/

Comment: ty David, it worked. I have posted an answer with a link to the utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reset windows password to blank using `chntpw` - a terminal utility on ubuntu.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/chntpw

Comment: Does this solve the original problem when the disk is put back in the laptop? If so then it wasn't a bios password issue and you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The chntpw *bootable cd or usb drive* (not an Ubuntu package) works.  http://www.chntpw.com/reset-windows-local-password-with-parted-magic/